# Free offline Speech Recognition SDK (API)

Tags: c#, api, asp.net, sdk

I want a SDK(API) for speech recognition. like google speech recognition. But it should be OFFLINE and FREE and also should compatible with ASP.NET C#.

any suggestion will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 3):

Windows has one in .net already.

[Get Started with Speech Recognition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh361683(v=office.14).aspx)

[SpeechRecognitionEngine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine(v=vs.110).aspx)

[SpeechRecognizer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognizer.aspx)

Just add a reference to  `System.Speech.dll`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,Actually I have tried this one. It's not accurate. Do you know more accurate one?